# If $A^TA$ is invertible and $W$ is square what is $\operatorname{rank}A^TWA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Consider $A ∈ \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $W ∈ \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ such that $n < m$ and $A^TA$ is invertible. If we know that $ \operatorname{rank}W = w \ge n $ what can we say about $\operatorname{rank}(A^TWA)$? My intuition is $ n + w - m \le \operatorname{rank}(A^TWA)$ but I can't prove it. I think using $ \operatorname{rank}(A^TWA) \ge \operatorname{rank}(A^TW) + \operatorname{rank}A - m $ may be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed formula can't be true. Consider $n=1, m=2$ and $A= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $A^TA=(1)$ is an invertible $1 \times 1$-matrix. With $W= \begin{pmatrix} 0& 1\\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ we have $\mathrm{rank}(W)=w =2 >n =1$. However, $A^TWA = (0)$ has rank zero. Since $n+w-m = 1+2-2=1$ in this case, the inequality $n+w-m \le \mathrm{rank}(A^TWA)$ can't be true.

In general it is true that $\mathrm{rank}(WA) \ge n+w-m$ since the image of $A$ contains $n$ linearly independent vectors of which at most $m-w$ can be send to $0$ or to linearly dependent images, so the rank has a lower bound of $n-(m-w) = n+w-m$. However, if we now apply $A^T$, it is possible that all the vectors in the image of $WA$ are in the kernel of $A^T$ since $A^T: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ maps into a lower-dimensional space, so it has $m-n > 0$ linearly independent directions mapping to $0$.
Since at most $m-n$ vectors can be mapped to $0$, we have $n+w-m -(m-n) = 2n+w-2m$ as a lower bound for $\mathrm{rank}(A^TWA)$. Note that this number can be negative, depending on $n,m$ and $w$.

Comment: Thank you for your example. So the lower bound actually is zero! Thanks for explanation.